# MATLAB on the web

Tags: matlab, web, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Is it possible to install a MATLAB exe file along with its MCR on a web server and have some front end html code interact with it in terms of inputs and outputs? What web hosting server would be ideal for this? Will php make interacting with the web server easier?

The MATLAB code has multiple inputs that I want to have the user input into a form and each of those text fields corresponds to the a specific input. Once the user presses submit I want to run the MATLAB program on the server with the given inputs, and then display the array of outputs. Is that possible? Sorry, I am pretty savy with MATLAB but not with its Compilers, Coders, etc and not with web development either.

Comment: Knowing Mathworks, they will make you pay $2000 for each HTTP request sent to MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

[Options for Deploying MATLAB Applications via the Web](http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/new_products/webserver_discontinued.html;jsessionid=51bcff69220f6925814018c7e4e6?s_cid=r2006b_webserver)

[Deploying MATLAB Code as a Web Application](http://www.mathworks.com.au/desktop-web-deployment/deploying-code-web-application.html)

Comment: Page not found to the second link.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly this use case I created the project [NuCompRes](https://github.com/decatur/NuCompRes). There you also find a legal notice with respect to the MATLAB license.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario you have two options:

1-Compile your matlab code (no GUI) using MATLAB Builder JA (Java) or MATLAB Builder NE (dot NET). In that way you can create a jar or dll file with your Matlab code that can be invoked inside a web application created in java or aspx. This solution is fine if you have few users over the web. For this approach you need to have/buy the Matlab builder JA/NE in order to compile your matlab code properly.

2-The second approach, is to use MATLAB Production Server. This is a more complex (and more expensive) solution. Basically MATLAB Production Server is a software which must be intalled in a (web) server, which can handle multiple request of MATLAB functions executions at the same time and is able to comunicate java or dot net application with MATLAB code. This software comes in blocks of 24*n users licenses (24 user, 48 users, and so on) and can manage MATLAB functions/libraries created in different MatLab versions.

In both cases you must create in MatLab your core code (the heavy and mathematical part of your computation) and invoke it inside the web application (at this time The Mathworks only supports Java and dot net). The GUI part is not expected to be created in MATLAB.